# Linear independence and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Regard $\mathbb R^2$ as a  vector space over $\mathbb Q$.  Then $(1,0)$ and $(\sqrt2,0)$ are $\mathbb Q$-linear independent, but their determinant equals zero.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the fact that $\mathbb R^2$ is not a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$. You are making an implicit (and false) assumption that $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ is a basis for your vector space, but it isn't.

Determinants as a means of determining linear independence are only useful for finitely-dimensional spaces.

Comment: I was aware that the dimension is infinite.  Just for curiosity: is the dereminant definable on infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Considering $\mathbb C^2$ as a $\mathbb R$-vector space, the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(i,0)$ are $\mathbb R$-linear independent, yet their determinant is zero.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Your example if $(1,0), (i,0)$ again assumes the wrong dimensionality, because you are again assuming that $(1,0),(0,1)$ is a basis for $\mathbb C^2$, when in fact you have $4$ basis vectors. And for your first question, I don't know of any "infinite-dimensional-generalization" of determinants.

Comment: About your question "is the determinant definable on infinite-dimensional vector spaces?", take a look to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant).